# error con una ordenamiento de vector en burbuja

Tags: array, ordenamiento, pseint, pseudocódigo, ordenar

buenas tengo un error al intentar hacer esto pero me da error, por ej este fue testeado con un vector de 2 elementos

LINEA 17: ERROR 302 SUBINDICE 2 FUERA DE RANGO (0..1)

He tratado de cambiarle absolutamente todo pero no anda, el error es del condicional pero yo creo que podria tratarse del segundo para

```
SubProceso crearv(vector Por Referencia, d)
    Definir num, i Como Entero
    Para i = 0 Hasta d-1 Hacer
        Escribir  "Ingrese el número ", i+1, " de ", d, ": "
        Leer num
        vector[i] = num
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

SubProceso ordenarVector(vector Por Referencia, d)
    Definir min, aux, i, j Como Entero
    Si d <= 0 Entonces
        Escribir "Error: El vector está vacío o tiene una longitud de 0."
    SiNo
        Para i = 0 Hasta d - 1 Hacer
            Para j = 0 Hasta d - i - 1  Hacer
                Si vector[j] > vector[j+1] Entonces
                    aux = vector[j]
                    vector[j] = vector[j+1]
                    vector[j+1] = aux
                Fin Si
            Fin Para
        Fin Para
    FinSi
FinSubProceso

SubProceso mostrarv(vector Por Referencia, d)
    Definir i Como Entero
    Para i = 0 Hasta d-1 Hacer
        Escribir vector[i]
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

Algoritmo ej5dia18
    Definir vector, d Como Entero
    Escribir "¿Cuántos números va a ingresar?"
    Leer d
    Dimension vector[d]
    crearv(vector, d)
    ordenarVector(vector, d)
    mostrarv(vector, d)
FinAlgoritmo


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLTHu.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido, antes que nada, te aclaro que no uso pseudo-código, por lo que todo lo que te diga, debes constatarlo, pero si corregí y ejecuté tu código en pseint.

```
SubProceso crearv( vector Por Referencia, d )
    Definir num, i Como Entero
    Para i = 1 Hasta d  Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir  "Ingrese el número ", 1, " de ", d, ": "
        Leer num
        vector[ i ] = num
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

SubProceso ordenarVector( vector Por Referencia, d )
    Definir min, aux, i, j Como Entero
    Si d <= 0 Entonces
        Escribir "Error: El vector está vacío o tiene una longitud de 0."
    SiNo
        Para i = 1 Hasta d Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Para j = 1 Hasta d - i  Con Paso 1 Hacer
                Si vector[ j ]  > vector[ j + 1 ] Entonces
                    aux = vector[ j ]
                    vector[ j ] = vector[ j + 1 ]
                    vector[ j + 1 ] = aux
                Fin Si
            Fin Para
        Fin Para
    FinSi
FinSubProceso

SubProceso mostrarv( vector Por Referencia, d )
    Definir i Como Entero
    Para i = 1 Hasta d Hacer
        Escribir vector[ i ]
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

Algoritmo ej5dia18
    Definir vector, d Como Entero
    Escribir "¿Cuántos números va a ingresar?"
    Leer d
    Dimension vector[ d ]
    crearv( vector, d )
    ordenarVector( vector, d )
    mostrarv( vector, d )
FinAlgoritmo
```

Por lo que estuve viendo, los `array` arrancan de posición "`1`" (lo que te obliga a cambiar la condición de parada, quitando el `-1`), y en los "`Para`" debes declarar el salto, con "`Con Paso`" y el entero correspondiente, con esas mínimas modificaciones, funciona!!